# Best Choice Regex for extract the Facebook Link

Tags: php, regex

i search the best regex method for the most functionality.

I search on Google and will extract the Facebook Links. Because Google has no Search API that works 1to1 with the exact Google Results i don't can use the API.

I send now a normal request to google, extract the html code and will find all Facebook Link without google parameters.

Examples you find on regex debbuger.

I will see only this links if is possible.

Here Example Strings to search:
     `

```
 /url?q=https://www.facebook.com/pageid/about&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi27NeDvfTTAhWBfywKHbuDDS4QjBAIHDAB&usg=AFQjCNH7T2JEP5DzGpiiwT_pMt2oGJ10ow

 /url?q=https://www.facebook.com/pageid/%3Fpnref%3Dlhc&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiWv8S6vfTTAhUEBiwKHW04AH8Q_BcIyQQoATBu&usg=AFQjCNEZIUb1yqqYtzjPfDEVi4GPHDY5FQ

 /url?q=https://www.facebook.com/pageid%3Fpnref%3Dlhc&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiWv8S6vfTTAhUEBiwKHW04AH8Q_BcIyQQoATBu&usg=AFQjCNEZIUb1yqqYtzjPfDEVi4GPHDY5FQ

/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/name-name-585606818284844/%3Fpnref%3Dlhc&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiWv8S6vfTTAhUEBiwKHW04AH8Q_BcIyQQoATBu&usg=AFQjCNEZIUb1yqqYtzjPfDEVi4GPHDY5FQ

/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/name-name-585606818284844%3Fpnref%3Dlhc&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiWv8S6vfTTAhUEBiwKHW04AH8Q_BcIyQQoATBu&usg=AFQjCNEZIUb1yqqYtzjPfDEVi4GPHDY5FQ`
```

Thats my Regex this works but not for all options. Regex Debugger:

https://regex101.com/r/LcYz8c/8

Comment: How about https://regex101.com/r/LcYz8c/10?

Comment: `(https?:\/\/(?:.*?\.)?[facebook|fb].com\/.*)[&#]`

Comment: degant i dont want the fullstring: https://www.facebook.com/derName/1232423425324532&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiDyPSRp_PTAhUMPRoKHQ0SC5EQFggaMAE&usg=AFQjCNH4D2ChQRXK2OHrF1KAF25558fWRQ . --- i will only https://facebook.com/derName... not the rest from google

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/LcYz8c/18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

<strike>"q=(https?://.*?facebook.com/)derName-/"</strike>

```
 "q=(https?://.*?facebook.com/)derName(?:%[^%]*%..|[-/])?([^&]‌​+)"
```

might be what you are looking for.  From what I see in your example, it looks like you want:
everything from the http up to the first / after the domain.  Then skip the derName, and then grab everything up to the next &.  So this is going to use 2 capture groups.  Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you that is better but the first string dont works can u help me? https://regex101.com/r/LcYz8c/16

Comment: Answer has been updated :)   That looks to work, but it is a bit hard coded to that first string.  I'm not sure what other patterns they throw at you.  If you want to dump a bunch of URLs at me I can give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
q=(https:\/\/www.facebook.com.*?)&
```

https://regex101.com/r/LcYz8c/11

Comment: Thanks that looks good i have been updated it similar. https://regex101.com/r/LcYz8c/12

Comment: Great ! Good luck and have nice coding :)

Comment: thank you sir i have update it https://regex101.com/r/LcYz8c/18 but it works not perfect :S